# Apply style to IMG elements only where no other style applied

Tags: html, css

I feel a bit silly asking this because it's so basic, however I appear to be stuck.

Using CSS I want to apply a style to all the IMG elements on the page where no other class has been applied.

So, for example let's say I want all my images on my page to have have a red border, unless a class is applied which says different. This is basic stuff, right?  But I'm finding that my other classes are overridden by the base IMG class.

In the following simple example I would like a red border on the top image and a green border on all the others:

CSS:

```
<style>
  IMG {  
     /* I want this to apply to all images except those where other style applied */
     border: solid 12px red;
     width:50%;
   }

  IMG:nicepic {
     border:solid 12px green;
   }
</style>
```

EDIT:   Problem was a typo and nothing more. `IMG:nicepic` should have read `IMG.nicepic`  ("." instead of ":").  This entire question is based on a simple typo in my CSS; I tried to delete the question but was denied permission to do that by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey there is small change

CSS CODE

```
IMG {  
     /* I want this to apply to all images except those where other style applied */
     border: solid 12px red;
     width:50%;
   }

  IMG.nicepic {/*not (:) is (.)*/
     border:solid 12px green;
   }
```

See Demo http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/ygco1ahf/

Answer (score 2):

The class selector in css is a dot `(.)`:

```
img.nicepic { /*not img:nicepic*/
   border:solid 12px green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just create a separate class for the first image, so you won't have to use the general "img"?

Comment: Good question and the reason I'm doing this is that I have a blog page where users can embed images in blog posts; these are naturally classless and I want to make them look a certain way when classless, eg. bordered and shadowed instead of expecting the user to specify a class when writing their blog post.